# Efficiently filter out matching rows between two 2-D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that look like

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,3], [5,6], [8,7]])
```

I want to filter to rows that are in array a, and not in array b. So my output should look like:

```
in_a_and_not_b = np.array([[3,4], [7,8]])
```

I have some nasty code to do this right now:

```
in_a_and_not_b = []
current_row = 0
for row_a in a:
    include_current_row = True
    for row_b in b:
        if np.array_equal(row_a, row_b):
            include_current_row = False
    if include_current_row:
        in_a_and_not_b.append(a[current_row])
    current_row += 1
```

My problem is that this takes forever. Is there a more numpy-thonic way to do this that will take less time?

In reality, my arrays a and b are large, around (50000, 2) in shape each.

Comment: if you convert to list of tuples then you can do `set(tuples_a) - set(tuples_b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert arrays to `list of tuples` then you can do `set(tuples_a) - set(tuples_b)`

---

Minimal working example

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
b = np.array([[1,2], [3,3], [5,6], [8,7]])

tuples_a = [tuple(x) for x in a.tolist()]
tuples_b = [tuple(x) for x in b.tolist()]

print( set(tuples_a) - set(tuples_b) )
```

Result:

```
{(3, 4), (7, 8)}
```

And next you can convert it to numpy.array.

But if you need to keep order then it may have problem.

Comment: TIL this solution is ~3x faster for *a,b* shape (50000,2) than `np.array(list({tuple(i) for i in a} - {tuple(i) for i in b}))`, mainly because of converting to and iterating over a `list` is much faster than iterating over a 2D-`np.array`.

Comment: Thanks Furas, I can confirm that made my function go from taking minutes to run down to less than a second!